# How to load settings before rest of node app?

Tags: node.js, synchronization, settings

I would like to load the settings for my `node` application before the app loads, so the settings will be available as the code is loaded. I can get a `LoadSettings.js` file to run using `--require` but the promise that loads the settings doesn't resolve before the app is loaded. Is there a way that I can force `node` to wait for the promise to resolve before the loading of this require completes and the rest of the app is loaded?

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of just put the `require()` in your app?

Comment: We're working on migrating to using `import()` with `esm` to simplify our code base a bit and even if we could put the `require()` in our app, then we'd have the same problem of the promise not resolving before the rest of the code started to load.

Comment: if you use `require()`, you could create an async helper function then `await Promise.all(settings); app.listen()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync). Here's an example:

```
import settings from './settings';

let done = false;

function loadSettings() {
    console.log('Loading settings');
    return settings.load().then(() => {
        console.log('Loaded settings');
        done = true;
    });
}

loadSettings();

require('deasync').loopWhile(() => {
    return !done;
});
```